# How should the weights for a WeightedRandomSampler be created for object detection when the labels are logits?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-classification, overfitting-underfitting

I've been trying to classify the VOC2007 dataset using CNN. The dataset has an imbalance, with multiple images having 'person' class and all the other classes have very few images and my model has been suffering from overfitting. In order to over sample I have been using the WeightedRandomSampler in my dataloader.

```
weights=[0.00000001,1/112,1/116,1/180,1/81,1/139,1/97,1/376,1/163,1/224,1/69,1/97,1/203,1/139,1/120,0.00001,1/133,1/48,1/111,1/127,1/128]

sample_weights=[0]*len(ds_train)

for idx, (data, label) in enumerate(ds_train):
 
  sample_weights[idx]=np.dot(weights, label)
 

sampler=WeightedRandomSampler(sample_weights,num_samples=len(sample_weights), replacement=True)
```

This does not give me a balanced dataset. I'm sure there is something wrong with my code and this is not how weights have to be created for a coco dataset. But I am not sure what should be done. How should weights be created for a dataset having logits as labels. How to perform oversampling for a coco image dataset with 20 classes?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the correct class weight to each instance of the dataset depending on their class. The straight forward way of going about this is to index an array of class weights with the dataset list of labels:

```
>>> weights= np.array([0.00000001, 1/112, 1/116, 1/180, 1/81, 1/139, 1/97, 1/376, \ 
                       1/163, 1/224, 1/69, 1/97, 1/203, 1/139, 1/120, 0.00001, \
                       1/133,1/48,1/111,1/127,1/128])

>>> sample_weights = weights[[label for _, label in ds_train]]
```

Then you can construct the sampler:

```
>>> sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(sample_weights, 
                                    num_samples=len(sample_weights), 
                                    replacement=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem with the statement where the sample weights are being set is that the labels are not an integer, it is an array of length 21(which is the number of classes) and since the images have more than 1 class in each image, so the label is something like this [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0 ]. How should sampling be done in this case?